# Can Apache Solr Handle TeraByte Large Data

Tags: solr, lucene, large-data-volumes, large-data

I am an apache solr user about a year. I used solr for simple search tools but now I want to use solr with 5TB of data. I assume that 5TB data will be 7TB when solr index it according to filter that I use. And then I will add nearly 50MB of data per hour to the same index.

1-  Are there any problem using single solr server with 5TB data. (without shards)

- a-   Can solr server answers the queries in an acceptable time
- b-   what is the expected time for commiting of 50MB data on 7TB index.
- c-   Is there an upper limit for index size.

2-  what are the suggestions that you offer

- a-   How many shards should I use
- b-   Should I use solr cores
- c-   What is the committing frequency you offered. (is 1 hour OK)

3-  are there any test results for this kind of large data

There is no available 5TB data, I just want to estimate what will be the result.

Note: You can assume that hardware resourses are not a problem.

Comment: A question for you. Assuming you are indexing 5TB of raw data, why do you think it will grow to 7TB? Should I take this to mean that you are storing the full document content in the index as well, as opposed to just storing the search fields? If so, I would suggest only storing what you need for searching in Solr. The raw documents themselves belong elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

if your sizes are for text, rather than binary files (whose text would be usually much less), then I don't think you can pretend to do this in a single machine.

This sounds a lot like [Logly](http://loggly.com/) and they use SolrCloud to handle such amount of data.

ok if all are rich documents then total text size to index will be much smaller (for me its about 7% of my starting size). Anyway, even with that decreased amount, you still have too much data for a single instance I think.

Comment: But 50MB per hour means aprox not 0.75TB per month, it is 0.075TB which means 75GB per month

Comment: sorry not sure how I got my calculations so wrong. Anyway the intial data is too large for a single solr I think...

Comment: In your opinion what is the optimal data size for single solr server

Comment: the 5TB, is it just text or binary files (.doc .pdf...)